# How to convert ISO timestamp to unix timestamp in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, datetime

i have this date output from aws cli "**`2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00`**".

I need to convert this string to unixtimestamp and the perform some calculation in shell script.
if calculation is true then add +1day to this output in same format ex ("2020-08-14T12:30:00+00:00"), else keep the same as it is.

**How to convert "2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00" to unixtimestamp and how to add +1 day in "2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00"**

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert "2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00" to unixtimestamp

```sh
date --date '2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00' +%s
```

> how to add +1 day in "2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00"

```sh
date --date '2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00 + 1 day'
```

Comment: When I answered a bash question with duplicates I got massive downvotes (even though the duplicate question was not raised when I posted). This is obviously a duplicate, so be prepared.

Comment: this is not working for me:

```
date --date '2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00' +%s 
date: invalid date `2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00' 

date --date '2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00 + 1 day'
date: invalid date `2020-08-13T12:30:00+00:00 + 1 day'
```